# Wordpress Rewrites my Html Pages

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress based website, and i want to add an html page.
The problem is that the Permalink Wordpress System interprets my www.website.com/page.html as an article and gives me 404 error.
What to do ?
My page is www.website.com/page.html( i have only a simple text ).

I tried with :

```html
RewriteRule test.html test.php [L]
```

into my .htaccess file but no solution.

my htaccess

```html
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 7

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /website
RewriteRule ^page-([^.]+)\.html$ article.php?art=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^portofoliu-([^.]+)\.html(.*)$ category.php?key=$1&q=%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^googled8f5c3c57ae1538c\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ article.php?key=$1 [L]

# all non www go to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.ro
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
#Header set Expires "11/02/2012 20:00:00"
</filesMatch>

#<IfModule mod_charset_lite.c>
#AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</ifmodule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Usually the `.htaccess` rules will leave files alone.  Can you past your full `.htaccess`?  And can you check (eg with Chrome dev tools) that your browser hasn't cached a redirect?

Comment: The rule you've posted seems wrong by the way - I'd delete it.  I'm pretty sure it's saying "if someone requests test.html, show them test.php"

Comment: I have a default wordpress installation, and /page.html opens perfectly, so posting your .htaccess is a good idea

Comment: i posted my htaccess

Comment: Looks like this line `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ article.php?key=$1 [L]` might be the culprit.  If I read that right, it's saying "send any URLs ending .html to article.php".  You might need a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before it somewhere (though I'm no expert, or I'd have written an answer...).  Or you could try renaming the file to `test.htm` to check

Comment: No, i need .html. Anyone else?